# spring security: Generate authentication from jwt

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

Here my configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder reactiveJwtDecoder() throws Exception {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec("JAC1O17W1F3QB9E8B4B1MT6QKYOQB36V".getBytes(), mac.getAlgorithm());

        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(secretKey)
            .macAlgorithm(MacAlgorithm.HS256)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(
        HttpSecurity http
    ) throws Exception {
        Customizer<OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity>> oauth2Customizer = (config) -> config.jwt();
        return http
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .csrf().disable()
        .formLogin().disable()
        .anonymous().disable()
        .logout().disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
        .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/gicar/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2Customizer)
        .build();
    }

}
```

Everything works fine.

I need to allow method execution according to jwt token information.

I know that in order to get that, I need to transform the jwt token to an `Authentication` object.

From my configuration on, what should I add to it, in order to generate an `Authentication` object and translate claims to authorities?

What I need to do is something like this:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/qdcf")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Timed
public class QdCFController {

    private final UsuariRepository usuariRepository;

    @GetMapping("/user")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole(ADMIN)")
    public Optional<Usuari> user() {
        return this.usuariRepository.findOne(UsuariSpecs.hasCodi("11111111A"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is already enough for Spring to create an `Authentication` object, the question is how it's going to get roles from your JWT.
To "guide" Spring and your `JwtDecoder` you should create and configure a bean of `JwtAuthenticationConverter` type, e.g. like this:

```java
@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    final JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter grantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    // choose a JWT claim name where authorities are stored on login
    // authorities claim name defaults to "scope" and "scp" if this method is not used
    grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");
    // here choose a scope prefix that was used
    // prefix defaults to "SCOPE_" if this method is not used
    grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("");

    final JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedAuthoritiesConverter);
    return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
}
```

This configuration will help `JwtDecoder` to translate any authority in the *"roles"* claim of JWT to `GrantedAuthority` with no prefix.